# Mongo secure database

Tags: mongodb

I'mnew on mongo and I'm finding some diferencces with SQL database, I'have created a database and I have created an user this way

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "chatlearning",
    pwd: "mypass",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "chatlearning" }]
  }
)
```

But I can acces to the database with mongodb compass without introducing any login ingo , what do I have to avoid the access to the database to any other user that not intruces the login?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: The documentation is correct, however I think they use a poor example. Typically users are alwys created in built-in `admin` database.

Answer (score 0):

After creating user have you restarted the mongo server in `auth` mode?

Here the process to start the `mongod` with access control enabled.

If you start the `mongod` from the command line, add the `--auth` command line option:

`mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

If you start the `mongod` using a configuration file (`/etc/mongod.conf`), add the `security.authorization` configuration file setting:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```